# not able to display the key value from map

Tags: map

I used apex:repeat and apex:datalist to display all the fields from the map. I am able to display only the values in the map not the key value from the map. Can anyone here can help me out what is the issue. 
VF :

```
  <apex:dataList value="{!sObjectFieldMap}" var="sobj">
        {!sobj}
        {!sObjectFieldMap[sobj]}
    </apex:dataList>
```

controller :

```
public with sharing class survey_ResultV2Ctrl{
public Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public Map<SObject, List<Schema.SObjectField>> sObjectFieldMap {get; set;}
public List<Schema.SObjectField> sObjectFieldLst = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();
public List<wrapperClass> wcls {get; set;}
public set<Schema.SObjectType> objNameSet =  new set<Schema.SObjectType>();
public Schema.SObjectType sobjtyp;
public survey_ResultV2Ctrl(){
    sObjectFieldMap = new  Map<SObject, List<Schema.SObjectField>>();
    wcls =  new List<wrapperClass>();
    survey_ResultDisplay();
}

public void survey_ResultDisplay(){

    for(Filter_Field_Set__c ffs : [SELECT Name, Field_Set_Category__c, Object_Fields__c, Object_Fields_Name__c FROM Filter_Field_Set__c Where Field_Set_Category__c = 'a0F9000000R5Fau']){
        system.debug('All the result from Filter Field Set object ' + ffs.Name);
        system.debug('Schema Map contains Key as object name ' + schemaMap.containsKey(ffs.Name));
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(ffs.Name).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        if(schemaMap.containsKey(ffs.Name)){
            system.debug('Schema object Values ' + schemaMap.get(ffs.Name));
            system.debug('All the fields related to Schema object ' + fieldMap.get(ffs.Object_Fields_Name__c));

            if(sObjectFieldMap.containskey(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name).newSObject())){
                sObjectFieldLst.add(fieldMap.get(ffs.Object_Fields_Name__c));
                //sobjtyp = schemaMap.get(ffs.Name);
                sObjectFieldMap.put(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name).newSObject(), sObjectFieldLst.clone());
                //objNameSet.add(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name));
                //wcls.add(new wrapperClass(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name), sObjectFieldLst));
                sObjectFieldLst.clear();
            }
            else{
                sObjectFieldLst.add(fieldMap.get(ffs.Object_Fields_Name__c));

                sObjectFieldMap.put(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name).newSObject(), sObjectFieldLst.clone());
                //wcls.add(new wrapperClass(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name), sObjectFieldLst));
                //objNameSet.add(schemaMap.get(ffs.Name));
            }
        }

    }


    system.debug('The wapper class after loop ' + wcls);
    system.debug('The Map after loop ' + sObjectFieldMap);

}


public with sharing class wrapperClass{

    public list<Schema.SObjectField> fieldname {get; set;}
    public Schema.SObjectType objectName {get; set;}

    public wrapperClass(Schema.SObjectType objectName, list<Schema.SObjectField> fieldname){
         objectName = objectName;
         fieldname = fieldname;
    }
}   
}
```

please help me get the solution.

Comment: Complex type can not be part of MAP key if iterating, well explained by crmprogdev

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain how you're using this class, but the key in your wrapper class is the `sObject` or `Schema.SObjectType objectName`. Are you wanting to display `objectName` as part of your field list? I ask because I don't see where you're trying to display records. I'm assuming `{!sobj}` isn't displaying. If that's the case, you may need to do an `<apex outputtext>` for each `{!sobj}` to get it to display the `sObjectType` or `objectName`.